# Lists in a dictionary not getting updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

In the following code, I am trying to store the count of each lowercase alphabet so that at `cnt[char][i + 1]` gives the count of letter 'char' till the ith character in the string.

```
import string
s = 'abcdabcd'
n = len(s)
cnt = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, [[0] * (n + 1)] * 26))
print('Before')
print(cnt)
for i in range(n):
    for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
        cnt[char][i + 1] = cnt[char][i] + (1 if char == s[i] else 0)
print('After')
print(cnt)
```

But, the output shows that the lists are not getting modified as they are initially filled with zeros, and even after the loop, they don't get modified.

I am unable to understand why is it happening and how to get the desired output.

Comment: `[[0] * (n + 1)] * 26` will make **26 references to the same list**.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, now I understand the problem. But how should I initialize the above dictionary so that all keys don't refer to the same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your dict with new lists:

```
import string
s = 'abcdabcd'
n = len(s)
cnt = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, [[0 for _ in range(n + 1)] for __ in range(26)]))
print('Before')
print(cnt)
for i in range(n):
    for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
        cnt[char][i + 1] = cnt[char][i] + (1 if char == s[i] else 0)
print('After')
print(cnt)
```